# UWP (C#) Bluetooth DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync not returning paired device

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm writting a Universal Windows App for my Raspberry Pi 3 (Windows 10 IoT Core v.10.0.15063.0) where I connect to a bluetooth device (ELM327) to obtain data about a car like speed, RPM, etc.

The problem is that sometimes when I'm starting the communication with the device using this code snippet:

```
_deviceCollection =
            await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
                RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                    RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

It returns no device: _deviceCollection.Count = 0

The bluetooth device is paired with my raspberry.

I added bluetooth support in my Package.appxmanifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
<DeviceCapability Name="location" />
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

I try to restart the pi, unpair and pair again my devices, sometimes it works, some it does not.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this `DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
                RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                    RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));` ? Here is [a sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it didn't work too. Same thing, no device is found is found.